# Dart replacing the node in the abstract syntax tree

Tags: dart, abstract-syntax-tree, dart-analyzer

i want to replace print(a) with print(a+b) in the following code.

```
void main(){
   String a ="hey";
   String b ="there"; 
   print(\$a);
}
```

> cn is the AstNode & cn contains print($a)

Is their any way i can do this? Please help me, i am new to dart.

Comment: please help @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that. I think it would be helpful if you posted the code that demonstrates what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: This isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: no worries i have found myself an answer on google groups of dart

Comment: @RishabJain care to post the answer yourself?

Comment: @rinukkusu i have posted the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://happystudiess.blogspot.in/2017/08/dart-replacing-node-in-abstract-syntax-tree.html

this is the link for the answer.

Comment: https://happystudiess.blogspot.in/2017/08/dart-replacing-node-in-abstract-syntax-tree.html